# Suppress library comments from output with knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I noticed that some library comment manage to pass through the `knitr` options, with `R 3.0.1` and `knitr 1.5` running on Mac OSX 10.8.5. The following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<libraries, echo=FALSE, cache=TRUE, warning=FALSE, results='hide', cache.lazy=FALSE, message=FALSE>>=
library(memisc)
1+1
@

\end{document}
```

will still produce in the output

[image]

Is there any way to silence unequivocally and universally the libraries?

NOTE: I think it could be an issue related to how `knitr` manage the warning messages from `R`. In this specific case the warning message was successfully suppressed but not the annotation preceding the message.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on R 3.0.2 with knitr 1.5 on Ubuntu (in other words, the output is empty as expected). In your posts it is always helpful if you give the versions of the software involved in your issue. What versions of knitr and R are you using? What is the output of the 'knit' comand when you run it (there might be warnings)?

Comment: I have a warning from the library `memisc` when I run the script in terminal. `Warning message: package ‘memisc’ was built under R version 3.0.2` just after the very same lines that are also outputted when typesetting the PDF (`# Loading required...`)

Comment: @scottkosty I edited the question with R and knitr version

Comment: thanks. You added good info. However at this point I'm not sure your question is a question. You might want to rephrase it (e.g. "Why does knitr do this... on R 3.0.1?") or if you think it is a bug, [report it](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues)

Comment: I can't reproduce either. I would try cleaning out your `cache` directory ...

Comment: At this point message=FALSE hides these for me.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Following Yihui's advice, I found the best option to be to invoke the `warning=F` and `message=F` chunk options, like so:

````
```{r, message=F, warning=F}
library(memisc)
```
````

This was using knitr ("Knit HTML") with RStudio to process R markdown.

Comment: Better is `include = FALSE`.

Comment: These two don't work for me. Also ''include = FALSE'' doesn't show the results (plots).

Answer (score 9):

Try the following code:

```
library(memisc, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly=TRUE)
```

or

```
suppressMessages(library(memisc, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly=TRUE))
```

Comment: in theory, that is not necessary after you use the chunk option `message=FALSE`

Comment: But if your writing an Rscript, as opposed to Rmarkdown, this is what you need.